# MySQL detecting keywords in a prepared statement

Tags: mysql, sql

My code works so I feel dirty asking this question, but I can't seem to find anywhere using the same sort of technique so want to ask if there's anything blatantly wrong with it that I can't see.

I have a stored procedure where one input parameter decides which fields to return by putting it in between `SELECT` and `FROM ...` in a prepared statement - I guess this is prone to SQL injection so I've put a scan on the variable to reject anything if the parameter includes any of the dangerous keywords or delimiters:

Here, `x` could be `table1.col1, table1.col4, table2.col1`

```
IF LOCATE('DROP', x) > 0 OR LOCATE('INSERT', x) > 0 OR LOCATE('UPDATE', x) > 0
    OR LOCATE(';', x) > 0 OR LOCATE('DELETE', x) > 0 THEN
```

Am I missing something big here? Or is there actually a pre-made way to do this in MySQL maybe?

Comment: What if x equals `table1.dateINSERTion`? Your test will locate it... It will be better (but far from perfect) to insert a space like this `IF LOCATE('INSERT ', x) > 0`

Comment: MySQL's PREPARE function can't handle multiple SQL statements so a injection vector with semicon (`;`) won't help the attacker.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b8011

Comment: Thanks guys, very helpful, I was aware of words inside words that may be blocked, I did have `INSERT ` with space at one point then worried you don't always need a space after INSERT somehow, but as far as I'm concerned the only thing included should be field/table names which I define so it should be ok. Good to know `;` isn't needed either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a "premade" way, but regular expressions would simplify your code:

```
where x regexp 'DROP|INSERT|UPDATE|;|DELETE'
```

I'm not sure this does what you really want.  It will find `PREINSERTION` and `DELETING`.  But it is simpler and equivalent to your logic.

Comment: I'll take this as the accepted answer since it one-lines it and I can easily add a few more warning words if necessary.